# 5M+ rows on a view

Tags: mysql

Hy, I have the following problem:

- Have 1 header row on main table which is the key on the rest of my
  structure.
- 4 rows on a customer table
- 198 rows on a market table
- 90 rows on a variety table
- 118 rows on a package table
- and 72 rows on a caliber table

All of this rows are related by an header id, this is already ok, my problem is when I tried to make a view with a join on all of this tables because it's trying to make 5M+ rows, is there a way to make something on this?

I can make store procedures, more tables, materialized views, etc.
I'm using mysql version 5.6
 But I'm not sure where to start so I can give the client an instance where he can view all this data.

Hope you can guide me on where to find a solution to this, I'm never work on that large amount of data before.

This is my query for the view

```
SELECT 
    `customer_desc_tbl`.`code` AS `customer`,
    `market_desc_tbl`.`code` AS `market`,
    `variety_desc_tbl`.`code` AS `variety`,
    `package_desc_tbl`.`code` as `package`
FROM
    `cc_matriz_precios_proforma_recibidor` `ccpr`
    JOIN `customer_tbl` `rec` ON (`ccpr`.`id_header` = `rec`.`id_header`)
    JOIN `customer_desc_tbl` ON (`rec`.`idcustomer` = `customer_desc_tbl`.`idcustomer`)
    JOIN `market_tbl` `merc` ON (`ccpr`.`id_header` = `merc`.`id_header`)
    JOIN `market_desc_tbl` ON (`merc`.`idmarket` = `market_desc_tbl`.`idmarket`)
    JOIN `variety_tbl` `var` ON (`ccpr`.`id_header` = `var`.`id_header`)
    JOIN `variety_desc_tbl` ON (`var`.`idvariety` = `variety_desc_tbl`.`idvariety`)
    JOIN `package_tbl` `env` ON (`ccpr`.`id_header` = `package_tbl`.`id_header`)
    JOIN `package_desc_tbl` ON (`package_tbl`.`idpackage` = `package_desc_tbl`.`idpackage`)
```

Hope this err diagram helps

[image: err diagram]

Regards.

Comment: Obtain whole view result seems not to be your goal. How do you use your view and/or its resultset? do you really need in all 5M+ records?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code being used for the view? If the record counts in the tables are as you say, it sounds like you have some bad joins that are resulting in the excess rows.

Comment: sure, I've updated my question.

Comment: my main problem is because of all of the join are related, so if I have 4 customer, this join with 198 markets, that mean that for each customer I have 198 wich gives me 4*198=792 rows then if I had 90 varieties means 90 for each customer for each market, wich is 4*198*90=71280 rows and so on for all data

Comment: The joins look ok, I would suggest you start with the base table, do the select, then add the first join, then select again, then add the next join, select again, etc. Presumably at some point when you join in one of those tables, your number of rows will increase to that 5M you are seeing, that at least will help you see which table/join may be contributing to the problem and you can go from there.

Comment: I've already do that, when I reach package it fails.
The order goes:
customer, market, variety, package, caliber

Comment: Ok, do you need to get the data for the user just one time? Or will the user repeatedly request all this information? If its just one time you could run it on each customer id?

Comment: The user will repeatedly request this, I'm thinking on a store procedure with some parameters so the user helps me filter some info.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, that is alot of data for someone to be viewing repeatedly, filters will definitely help. One other note... are these tables getting written to alot? If not you could add indexes catered to the users requests to speed them up. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: How could I add indexes as you say?

Comment: By running an alter table command, see this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-do-i-add-indices-to-mysql-tables

Comment: oh, I thought it was some other kind of indexes. thanks!